# Font identification / recommendation: Cursive serif used for quotes

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to find this font or something similar as its really perfect for what I'm needing.. I'm looking for a cursive font, clear and italic many thanks! James

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one is close (but not 100% matchs) for the font on the picture

**FF Atma Serif Italic**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's rather like a Baskerville. Baskerville was an eighteenth-century English designer, so there are hundreds of variants now.

This one is [Linotype's](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/linotype/baskerville_com_italic/):

[image: Linotype Baskerville]

You might also look at a Bodoni, which has the unlooped ***w*** and splayed ***y***. Bodoni was also an eighteenth-century designer (Italian, though) so again there are hundreds of variants. Most have a marked difference between "thicks" and "thins", which isn't so apparent in your example.

Here's [Linotype's](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/linotype/bauer_bodoni_std_italic_adobe/) again:

[image: Linotype Bodoni]